# How to use twitter4j.Status.isRetweet() method

Tags: java, android, twitter4j

I am creating a twitter client for Android using twitter4j library.

I want the client to show "true" on some items of a Listview only if the item is Retweet.

Then I coded like below:

```
private class TweetAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Status> {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public TweetAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_tweet, null);
        }
        Status item = getItem(position);
        // setStatus(convertView, getItem(position));


        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        name.setText(item.getUser().getName());

        TextView screenName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.screen_name);
        screenName.setText("@" + item.getUser().getScreenName());

        TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText(item.getText());

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d(E) H:mm:ss");
        TextView time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.time);
        time.setText(sdf.format(item.getCreatedAt().getTime()));

        SmartImageView icon = (SmartImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        icon.setImageUrl(item.getUser().getProfileImageURL());


        if(item.isRetweet()){
            TextView rt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rted_by);
            rt.setText(String.valueOf(item.isRetweet()));
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

To my surprise, I get an extra amount of "true" even on some items which are not "Retweet".

And once I remove the if statement like below, I can get an appropriate amount of "true" or "false" on the appropriate items.

```
//if(item.isRetweet()){
            TextView rt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rted_by);
            rt.setText(String.valueOf(item.isRetweet()));
//}
```

So the problem is that the if statement doesn't work as I intend it to do.